# How can I make two completely different hidden services to communicate with each other?

Tags: onion-services

Hidden Services A and B are hosted on different servers having different live IP addresses and I need to make them communicate with each other , say a chat service between A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can communicate with each other using standard options for tor clients. For example tor provided SOCKS5 server, your hidden service must know how to communicate using SOCKS. There are other communication options as well - transparent network mapping by router and wrapper to make any application socks aware.